# component is not rendered when getting data from localStorage in an event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In an event handler when getting data from `localStorage` and assigning this data to state variables, component is not re-rendered to reflect new values

The logic is that to verify if localStorage exists and that there is data for the current id, then assign values to the state variables from localStorage, otherwise obtain the data from the endpoints and synchronize the localStorage

If these conditions are met I get the data from localStorage and assign values to the state variables, but the component no re render

```
if (hasLocalStorage() && existInLocalStorage(id)) {
  const [show, episodes, cast] = fetchFromLocalStorage(id);

  setShow(show);
  setEpisodes(episodes);
  setCast(cast);

  return false;
}
```

This is the full function

```
function clickHandler(id) {
  setIsSummaryLoading(true);
  setHasSummaryLoadingErrors(false);

  if (hasLocalStorage() && existInLocalStorage(id)) {
    const [show, episodes, cast] = fetchFromLocalStorage(id);

    setShow(show);
    setEpisodes(episodes);
    setCast(cast);

    return false;
  }

  const endpoints = [
    `/shows/${id}`,
    `/shows/${id}/episodes`,
    `/shows/${id}/cast`,
  ];

  const promises = endpoints.map((endpoint) => fetcher(endpoint));

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then((data) => {
      const [show, episodes, cast] = data;

      setIsSummaryLoading(false);

      syncLocalStorage({ id, data });

      setShow(show);
      setEpisodes(episodes);
      setCast(cast);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setHasSummaryLoadingErrors(true);
      setIsSummaryLoading(false);

      console.error(error.message);
    });
}
```

The other relevant functions are as follows

```
function syncLocalStorage({ id, data }) {
  let storage = localStorage.maze ? JSON.parse(localStorage.maze) : {};

  storage[id] = data;

  localStorage.maze = JSON.stringify(storage);
}

function fetchFromLocalStorage(id) {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.maze)[id];
}

function hasLocalStorage() {
  return localStorage.maze !== undefined;
}

function existInLocalStorage(id) {
  return id in JSON.parse(localStorage.maze);
}
```

This is the full component code

```
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState({});
  const [episodes, setEpisodes] = useState([]);
  const [cast, setCast] = useState(null);
  const [shows, setShows] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [hasErrors, setHasErrors] = useState(false);
  const [isSummaryLoading, setIsSummaryLoading] = useState(false);
  const [hasSummaryLoadingErrors, setHasSummaryLoadingErrors] = useState(false);

  function submitHandler(query) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setHasErrors(false);

    fetcher(`/search/shows?q=${query}`)
      .then((shows) => {
        const showList = shows.map((entry) => entry.show);

        setIsLoading(false);

        setShows(showList);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setHasErrors(true);
        setIsLoading(false);

        console.error(error.message);
      });
  }

  function clickHandler(id) {
    setIsSummaryLoading(true);
    setHasSummaryLoadingErrors(false);

    if (hasLocalStorage() && existInLocalStorage(id)) {
      const [show, episodes, cast] = fetchFromLocalStorage(id);

      setShow(show);
      setEpisodes(episodes);
      setCast(cast);

      return false;
    }

    const endpoints = [
      `/shows/${id}`,
      `/shows/${id}/episodes`,
      `/shows/${id}/cast`,
    ];

    const promises = endpoints.map((endpoint) => fetcher(endpoint));

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((data) => {
        const [show, episodes, cast] = data;

        setIsSummaryLoading(false);

        syncLocalStorage({ id, data });

        setShow(show);
        setEpisodes(episodes);
        setCast(cast);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setHasSummaryLoadingErrors(true);
        setIsSummaryLoading(false);

        console.error(error.message);
      });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler} />
        {hasErrors ? <HasErrors /> : null}
        {isLoading ? (
          <IsLoading />
        ) : (
          <Shows shows={shows} onClick={clickHandler} />
        )}
      </div>
      <ShowDetail
        show={show}
        isSummaryLoading={isSummaryLoading}
        hasSummaryLoadingErrors={hasSummaryLoadingErrors}
      />
      <ShowSummary
        episodes={episodes}
        cast={cast}
        isSummaryLoading={isSummaryLoading}
        hasSummaryLoadingErrors={hasSummaryLoadingErrors}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Thanks for your comments

Comment: can you share your  full code where the state is declared and how is it used

Comment: Sure, in a moment. I updated the question

Comment: can you log the state inside render to actually check if the render function is being called or not.

Comment: @user615274 Try logging the value of state just above the return function of the app and check wether state is changing or not

Comment: the state variables receive the values from localStorage I can verify it with react dev tool, even so it will not render again, for now I think it could be because the action of obtaining data from localStorage is a side effect, if so, how could I handle this case?

Comment: although I did find this example https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react#how-to-cache-data-in-react where in the same way Robin gets localStorage values in an event handler and then assigns the result to the state variable. I understand it works properly

Answer (score 0):

Set `setIsSummaryLoading` state variable to `false` solve the problem

```
if (hasLocalStorage() && existInLocalStorage(id)) {
  const [show, episodes, cast] = fetchFromLocalStorage(id);

  setShow(show);
  setEpisodes(episodes);
  setCast(cast);
  setIsSummaryLoading(false); // set to false

  return false;
}
```

The reason is that the components `ShowDetail` and `ShowSummary` receive the value of `isSummaryLoading` as property and as its value remained `true`

```
<ShowDetail
  show={show}
  isSummaryLoading={isSummaryLoading}
  hasSummaryLoadingErrors={hasSummaryLoadingErrors}
/>
<ShowSummary
  episodes={episodes}
  cast={cast}
  isSummaryLoading={isSummaryLoading}
  hasSummaryLoadingErrors={hasSummaryLoadingErrors}
/>
```

This is the code of ShowDetail component, and because `isSummaryLoading` was set to `true` only the `<IsLoading />` is rendered

```
function ShowDetail({ show, isSummaryLoading, hasSummaryLoadingErrors }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {hasSummaryLoadingErrors ? <HasErrors /> : null}
      {isSummaryLoading ? (
        <IsLoading />
      ) : (
        <>
          {Object.keys(show).length > 0 && (
            <>
              <h1>{show.name}</h1>
              <img src={show.image && show.image.medium} alt={show.name} />
              <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(show.summary)} />
              <ShowTable show={show} />
            </>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks to those who commented